# Why the text is not working any more when clicking on a cube/s as button/s?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is a screenshot of the Text ui where the numbers should be displayed when the player is pressing the numbers :

[image: Text ui]

If I will type in the text on my own in the inspector it will show it :

[image: Typed in inspector it's showing the numbers]

but if in the game I click with the mouse on the cube for example the cube on number 0 it's not showing 0 in the text ui. I enabled the key 0 mesh renderer just to show the cube on it for the example :

[image: Not showing the text 0 in the text ui]

No matter how many times I click on the buttons(cubes) it's not showing anything in the text ui.

This script is attached to each Cube(Button) :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using UnityEngine;

public class SecurityKeypadKeys : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMesh text;

    private void Start()
    {
        text = GameObject.Find("Security Keypad Text").GetComponent<TextMesh>();
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        string[] digits = Regex.Split(transform.name, @"\D+");
        foreach (string value in digits)
        {
            int number;
            if (int.TryParse(value, out number))
            {
                text.text = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And when I'm using a break point it does getting to the onmousedown event and there are 3 items in the array digits two items empty just empty string and one is a digit :

[image: digits array]

When the string is empty it's not getting to the text.text line only when there is a digit :
In this case text and value both 0 :

[image: text is 0]

but when I make continue and it's getting back to the game the text ui is empty.

Comment: You are assigning 

    `text.text = value;`

Have you tried instead using 

    `text.text = number.ToString();` .. and are you sure there is nothing else changing the text?

Comment: I found the problem and it's more then embarrassing, I have two ui texts the problem is that I duplicated the security keypad object and forgot to assign the second one text to the script on the buttons and instead each typed number was sent to the first text.

Comment: That is btw one big reason (besides performance) why `Find` should be avoided ;) instead reference your objects via the Inspector and skip your `Start` method :)